# Redirecting to another form in windows application c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using the below function to Close existing form and opening new form.
I am getting the below error when the code tries to close the existing form

Error :

{System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Screensaver' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Code :

```
   public static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        StartThread();
        Application.Run(new MyContext(new Screensaver()));
    }
    public class MyContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        static private Form curMain = null;

        public MyContext(Form main)
        {
            MyContext.NewMainForm(main, false);
        }

        static public void NewMainForm(Form main, bool ClosePreviousMain)
        {
            try
            {
                if (main != null)
                {
                    if (ClosePreviousMain & MyContext.curMain != null)
                    {
                        MyContext.curMain.FormClosed -= new FormClosedEventHandler(main_FormClosed);
                        MyContext.curMain.Close();
                    }

                    MyContext.curMain = main;
                    MyContext.curMain.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(main_FormClosed);
                    MyContext.curMain.Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.writeToLogFile(System.Environment.NewLine + "Message :  " + ex.Message.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine + "Stack :  " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }

        static private void main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that `MyContext.curMain` refers to a form that was created on another thread than the one that you are currently executing on when trying to close it (the call `StartThread();` and the exception message indicates that there is some threading going on). All attempts to execute any methods in `MyContext.curMain` must be performed on the thread that it was created on. This is achieved by using [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) or [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx), as such:

```
MyContext.curMain.Invoke(new Action(MyContext.curMain.Close));
```

Comment: Hi Fredrik Mörk,

      Closing the form works like charm now.
   But problem in showing the forms after closing the existing form.
Wats happening is, I am not getting any exception.Instead it opens a new process instead of opening the form.

The process name is same as the new form name.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Fredrik Mörk,

Its working now. i used.

MyContext.currform.ShowDialog();

Thanks